# javascript webdriver.io : click on specific coordinates

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Actually I click on a button and a pop over comes.
As I click anywhere outside the pop over, it goes. 
That's what I need to test.

Any suggestions ?

I am thinking to click on some coordinates on the page.
Tried doing it with :

```
1. element.click(coordinates here); // its not working
// Getting TypeError: selector.slice is not a function.

2. element.moveTo('#abc',100,100);
// now I want to click on the moved position but no success so far.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try browser.leftClick(selector,xoffset,yoffset);
and for selector the put element that overlays all page when popup is open for example

```
browser.leftClick('#cboxOverlay',100,100);
```

api documentation http://webdriver.io/api/action/leftClick.html#Usage

Comment: Can I remove the dependency from any selector ?
Just move to certain coordinates in the DOM and click.

Actually my purpose is to click on somewhere outside popover and I don't want to depend on any selector because it tends to change..

Comment: As here : http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/moveTo.html
'If no element is specified, the move is relative to the current mouse cursor'

How to provide no element. I left it blank, I tried with single quotes but they dint work.
Any guidance over it.

Comment: well in this case it is a bit harder, since the modal, popup or iframe goes over the whole page and you can not really interact with the page itself.
As in my example, #cboxOverlay is the parent of current popup. 
Just out of curiosity, the pop up should have X (closing) button and users tend to click on that to dismiss it. Therefore, clicking on other parts of the page is not a good practice of UX design.

Comment: about moveTo, I assume the api is looking of an element on current opened frame (your popup). In case it doesn't find it or leave it empty, it will throw an error

Comment: yes.. but we have just one button on it i.e to update data. For dismissal, you need to click on somewhere outside. 

Regarding #cboxOverlay, parent of my popup has two occurences in the DOM. So I am doing var element=browser.elements('#parent') and then return which is visible.

Now in my moveTo, How do i get selector out of it ?


element.selector or element.selectorById is returning Id which is again common for both the occurences. I hope my problem is clear here.

Comment: popover is like some element which is made visible when we click on some element. So I am able to interact with rest of the page as well.

Comment: can you present the live version of website and the element, may be I can have a look on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141327/discussion-between-bhavisha-and-k185).

Comment: Link is not working anymore (redirects to API overview). leftClick() seems to have been removed from latest wdio API.

Comment: .click() now is the substitute and it has options in the docs https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/click.html